# bash scan millions of files and scan for a value quickly

Tags: bash, shell

I have millions of files in a folder (nested). I need to scan a value from those files and print lines containing this value (say `LINE_TXT`). Earlier I used to sed each file but it used to take 45mins to do this. My earlier solution was something like this:

```
FILES=$(find $1 -type f -name 'filename.txt')
for f in $FILES
do
    if [[ "$LINE" == *LINE_TXT* ]]; then
        echo $LINE
    fi
done
```

I figured out that pipemill is best way to achieve this. My primary solution is something like this:

```
makefifo mypipe
find $1 -type f -name 'filename.txt' | xargs cat > my pipe &
while read -r LINE
do
    if [[ "$LINE" == *LINE_TXT* ]]; then
        echo $LINE
    fi
done << mypipe
```

Run time is 1min around. Can I improve on this further ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to me that less script overhead would make things faster.

```
fgrep -r -h 'LINE_TXT' $1
```

Just let grep do its own recursion through your directories with `-r`.  And if you don't want its output to include the filename in its output, include the `-h` option.  You can pipe its output through whatever you need for post-processing.

If you want to search only for specific filenames, grep's `-r` option has options of its own: `--include` and `--exclude`, mentioned on its man page.  For example:

```
fgrep -h -r --include '*/filename.txt' 'LINE_TXT' $1
```

While the `find` command is excellent, and invaluable in certain situations, if you can use options built in to a single tool like `grep`, you will incur less overhead.  The `find` command doesn't look inside files, so it would still have to launch `grep` for each one of them.  If you DID want to use `find`, it might look something like this:

```
find $1 -name 'filename.txt' -exec fgrep 'LINE_EXT' {} \;
```

This has the benefit of giving you access to `find`'s directory searching capabilities, but if all you want to do is look for a particularly named file in your directory tree, grep's `-r --include` is probably sufficient and is sure to run faster.

Comment: This works if you want to search all files; if you want a more specific search (to make it run faster) the `find` option is better.

Comment: Yes, there are files with different names inside each folder and I want to search specific file with file name: filename.txt

Comment: @AndersJohansson - Updated to include `--include`

Comment: @ghoti, interesting - didn't know about `--include`. Personally I still prefer `find` because it has more options, like find by permission, follow symlinks or not, etc. For this question though, your answer probably runs faster.

Comment: Also note that the last example, `find ... -exec fgrep ... \;` will launch a new `fgrep` instance for each match; this is very inefficient. If you instead pipe to `xargs` it will collect as many filenames as will fit on your commandline (usually hundreds or thousands), and execute a single `fgrep` searching all those files in one go, then repeat the process until all files have been searched.

Comment: @AndersJohansson - ya, I thought of that, but the OP said "millions of files", so I figured that wouldn't work.  I didn't have a folder with millions of files I could use for testing though. How would `xargs` know to stop building a command line and repeat the process?   I don't see any mention of ARG_MAX detection in `man xargs`.

Comment: @ghoti, `xargs` has its own max command line length, which can be overridden with option `-s`. Says `man xargs`: "`-s size` /.../ The current default value for size is `ARG_MAX - 4096`."

Comment: @AndersJohansson - Ah, true.  It would be interesting to see if grep is able to process millions of files on a single command line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `find $1 -type f -name 'filename.txt' | xargs fgrep LINE_TXT`, if all you want is to locate all matches of "LINE_TXT" in any of those files.

Comment: Sadly I need to process those lines further to extract more information.

Comment: Process how? If e.g. by a script/other command, you can just pipe that through: `find ... | xargs fgrep ... | process`

Comment: In that case you should use `find $1 -type f -name 'filename.txt' | xargs fgrep -H LINE_TXT` so that way it will print the filename as well and process that afterwards.

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai - no, you shouldn't do that.  Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs .  If you want to execute things on files found by `find`, you really need to figure out how to do it using `-exec`.

Comment: if filenames contain some stupid characters like spaces or else, you could use *zero terminated strings* passed from `find` to `xargs` in this manner:  `find $1 -type f -name 'file*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H LINE_TXT`

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact use case for tools [ack](https://beyondgrep.com/), [ag](https://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) and [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep). Not only are they more convenient to use than `grep -r`, but, at least the latter two, are much faster too.